# Writing a ELisp function to make man open in another window

Tags: emacs, manpage

So I know that `Man-notify-method` controls this, but I like to have the option to open it in the same window. By default, I have it to `pushy`. Currently, I have:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-m s") 'man)
```

and I would like to have

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-m o") 'man-other-window)
```

I am very new to Elisp, but I think it should be something as simple as:

```
(defun man-other-window ()
  "open a `man` in a new window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((Man-notify-method 'friendly))
      (man)))
```

but I get an error to do with wrong number of arguments, but when I pass an argument to the function, it doesn't work the way I like it. How can I get the behavior so that it would behave as:

```
M-x man-other-window RET relevant-man-page RET
```

just as `M-x man` does?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *>= Emacs 28.1*, as the simplest solution, try using [`other-window-prefix`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.28#L417) command, which is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> by default.

Namely:

- Hit <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>.
- See `Display next command buffer in a new window...` message.
- Hit <kbd>M-x</kbd> `man` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<command-name>`.
- Voilà.

The conveniency of `other-window-prefix` is that it could be used *on-the-fly* in many situations, without a need to write functions for all the cases you might encounter.

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `other-window-prefix` now outputs the following docstring:

```
Display the buffer of the next command in a new window.
The next buffer is the buffer displayed by the next command invoked
immediately after this command (ignoring reading from the minibuffer).
Creates a new window before displaying the buffer.
When ‘switch-to-buffer-obey-display-actions’ is non-nil,
‘switch-to-buffer’ commands are also supported.
```

For the similar conveniency bindings consult <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Pop Up Window")`. Notably, `same-window-prefix` is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: I ended up using `(call-interactively 'man)` and that did exactly what I wanted.